# Text does not fit the screen in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

The TextViews used in the following layout do not get wrapped in the screen and go out on the left (or start) edge of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"/>

        <TextView
            android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/thumbnail_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/video_thumbnail_image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/video" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I do not know why the text goes out of screen on the left side. I have tried using margin and padding for the `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` and the two `TextViews`, but none of them solved the problem.
 Currently, the app displays content as follows:
[image]

As you see in the code, I have also applied the `gravity` attribute to the TextViews, but no success yet. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Very complex question, can you let us know what do you mean by fit text in `LinearLayout` ? you have 3 `TextViews` and all working fine as properties set. Make sure you know how `LinearLayout` works

Comment: Did you try setting some padding to the LinearLayout enclosing the two textviews? (like about 10dp).

Comment: @jasonStack please use constraint layout its the better layout

Comment: Sorry @JibяaᴎKhaᴎ for sounding complex. The text start part is clipped and the whole text does not fit the the list item.

Comment: @KiranBennyJoseph I think I cannot use ConstraintLayout because this is a ListView item, which is in turn nested in a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: no you can use it

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:text="" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: it 's working check carefully..i will update image how it looks

Comment: use this line inside your Imageview `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@android:string/dialog_alert_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@android:string/fingerprint_icon_content_description"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_title" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_video_descr"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_img" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/text_padding"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Hi" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_video_descr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thumbnail_height"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_pane"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/video" />
</LinearLayout>
```